# Application screen recording in Android

Tags: android, screenshot, video-capture, android-mediaprojection

I want to record my own application's window. The only relevant API I see is [media projection](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/media-projection#java).
I would use it but it requires user consent because it enables screen capturing of other applications. I'm interested only in my own application screen.

Is there a way to record my application screen without media projection API (and without user consent)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible without requiring user consent. Android treats the screen of your app as part of the overall device screen, and the MediaProjection API is the only way to capture the screen of your app.

The MediaProjection API requires user consent as a security measure to prevent malicious apps from capturing the screen of other apps without the user's knowledge.

Comment: Don't you think it could be a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android Just take screenshot 23 times per second and compress?